# Using both date and duration in html5 <time> element's datetime attribute

Tags: html, datetime, time, semantics

I have a list of events, each of which has a start date and an end date and I would like to use the html5 `<time>` element to make the list semantically richer.

I have found that I can use the `datetime` attribute to provide a machine-readable time like so:

```
<time datetime="2015-02-21">my birthday</time>
```

I have also found that the attribute supports durations like so:

```
<time datetime="P2D">two days</time>
```

However, I haven't been able to find what is the correct way to combine the two in a single `<time>` element to, for example, display an event that begins on the 21st of February and lasts two days.

Can I simply use a date and a duration separated by a space:

```
<time datetime="2015-02-21 P2D">21.-23. February</time>
```

Or would the correct way be to use two `<time>` elements?

```
<div>
 <time datetime="2015-02-21">21.</time>
 -
 <time datetime="2015-02-23">23.</time>
 February
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to combine specific date strings or time strings with a duration string in a single `<time>` element. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) suggests using two `<time>` elements instead:

> **Code Example:**
>
> The time element can be used to encode dates, for example in microformats. The following shows a hypothetical way of encoding an event using a variant on hCalendar that uses the time element:
>
> ```
> <div class="vevent">
>  <a class="url" href="http://www.web2con.com/">http://www.web2con.com/</a>
>   <span class="summary">Web 2.0 Conference</span>:
>   <time class="dtstart" datetime="2005-10-05">October 5</time> -
>   <time class="dtend" datetime="2005-10-07">7</time>,
>   at the <span class="location">Argent Hotel, San Francisco, CA</span>
>  </div>
> ```

which closely matches the example that you have.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question! I guess I will go with the exact code example that I provided in my question for this specific case.

Comment: I don't know if I would say that `dtstart` and `dtend` don't convey any semantic value. Using those classnames is necessary to be parsed as an hCalendar event. So while they aren't necessary for plain `<time>` markup, they *do* convey additional semantic value for microformat parsers.

Comment: @jasonkarns: Ah, I didn't realize that. Even the spec says so. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -2):

do you want something like this?

```html
  <input type="date" min="2015-02-21" max="2015-02-23"/>
  
  <input type="date" min="2015-02-21" max="2015-02-23"/>
 February
```

however, it is not compatible with ie and firefox at presents. You'e better use a js dateSelector  plug-in instead.

Comment: I doubt it - they're not making a form.

Comment: @BoltClock is correct - I was merely interested in ways of displaying date information